# How to work around installer that uses outdated check for Visual C++

Tags: windows-8.1, installer, visual-c++

I have an installer for a really old application that I need to get installed on my Windows 8.1 PC. The installer does a check for Visual C++ 2005 SP 1, and if you don't have it, it prompts you to install it, and it redirects you to download it, except that download page redirects to a Microsoft 404.

I have VC++ 2005 SP 1 installed with both x86 and x64.

So, I decompiled the installer using JustDecompile, and the installer was in WinForms and used this code below to check for VC++ 2005 SP 1.

Basically if this line of code was true, it would show a message that you need to get VC++.

if (Form1.MsiQueryProductState("{7299052B-02A4-4627-81F2-1818DA5D550D}") != 5)

I've read about it and that was an acceptable way to check for VC++ 2005 in the time of the dinosaurs, but I believe that GUID above which is a product code is no longer accurate for Win 8.1 because I've gotten VC++ 2005 SP 1 directly from Microsoft and it's still not finding it.

Now, I'd like to figure out how to work around this problem. Does anyone know how the method MsiQueryProductState determines if you have something installed for a given product code? Does it look in the registry somewhere? If so, I could maybe work around this by faking it in the registry or something.

Any other suggestions appreciated!

Comment: MsiQueryProductState returns an enumeration value of 5 (INSTALLSTATE_DEFAULT) if the product is installed.  There were multiple versions of VC++ 2005 and they are not binary compatible with each other unlike VC++ 2017+.  What is the exact version of the library file you installed and what is the exact version of the same file that is required

Comment: Would it be feasible to temporarily change the Registry key from a later VC++ to the desired value? That said, I did *not* find these keys in the Registry: https://zzz.buzz/notes/vc-redist-packages-and-related-registry-entries/ and https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/astebner/2007/01/24/updated-vc-8-0-runtime-redistributable-packages-are-included-in-visual-studio-2005-sp1/

Comment: VC 2005 SP1 was a different version than VC2005 SP1 Update.  Have you tried to change the [product.xml](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/nikolad/2007/04/02/workaround-for-using-vs2005-sp1-version-of-vcredist-exe-within-a-boostrapper-setup-exe/)?

Comment: You can try modifying [application.exe.config](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/nikolad/2007/04/23/vs2005-sp1-version-of-visual-c-redistributable-package-is-available-for-download/) to match the file you actually have installed.

Comment: Apologies for the late reply here.  I am thinking it's likely that I'll have to make a registry change to basically make this MsiQueryProductState method think that I have the correct product code installed.  Because I can't find any way to get VC++ with this specific product code the installer is looking for.  I just need to figure out what registry change to make.  I don't have an application.exe.config with this installer, (it's called VirindiInstaller.exe, so would be VirindiInstaller.exe.config).  There's also no product.xml with the installer.  I'll look into these links, appreciate it.

Comment: [Answered with a proposal on stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57983432/how-does-msiqueryproductstate-determine-vc-is-installed/58017098#58017098).

Comment: Just to put some closure on this, I ended up finding someone who had a link to the correct VC++ installer with the product code that my installer was looking for.  It was only available on web.archive.org, Microsoft doesn't host it anymore.